# Multiple SDL_renderer per SDL_Window

Tags: c++, graph, sdl-2

During conversion of SDL1.2 to SDL2.x, I have following issue:

Cntext: Full screen application with 2 scroll-dialogs based on a SDL_Surface. Each scroll dialog has many items. I implemented swype in these parts of the screen. Next to this, there are several buttons on screen and images, and a background.

Problem: Because this is slow and has swype artefacts, I want to change to SDL2. Since SDL2 is completely different, I need advice an how to proceed.

What approach is best?

1. Use 1 Window, 3 SDL_renderer: 1 for the background and 2 for scrolling dialogs, and SDL_Texture for the images.
2. Use 1 Window, 1 SDL_renderer: Use 2x large SDL_Texture for the scrolling dialogs, and draw directly inside the scrolling dialogs.
3. Use 1 Window, 1 SDL_renderer and create SDL_Texture for each item and draw these on the SDL_renderer.
4. Use 1 Window, 1 SDL_renderer: Use 2x large SDL_Texture for the scrolling dialogs, and Textures for each item in the scrolling dialogs. Copy the item textures inside the scrolling texture, which is put on the SDL_renderer.

Please motivate what I should choose for architecture?

Comment: Are you thinking best as in "most efficient", or best as in "best design"?

Comment: For SDL2 I just want the most fast code. Because SDL1.2 is not nice to look at with smooth scrolling in SDL_Surface. Purpose for scrolling is a restaurant menu or a restaurant order. Imagine the menu card can be 5x the width of the display.. the order can be 100 items. Swype should be smooth here.

Comment: With SDL_RenderSetViewport I can also creating scrolling boxes, acting like I have more windows, in which I can scroll objects without having to take care of borders. This is a completely different approach than SDL1.2, but may work. Is that correct?